# I get a 502 Bad Gateway error with django app on AppEngine

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, web-deployment, gunicorn

I'm deploying a django app on Google app engine (flexible environment). The app works fine locally and the deployment (using `gcloud app deploy`) goes well. While the homepage loads well, I get a 502 Bad Gateway nginx error when I load some binary data (about 40Mo) using pickle from a directory in the same app directory (through a POST request). I've tried many proposed solutions (change the PORT to 8080, add the gunicorn timeout or add --preload, change n° of workers..), but still have the problem. I think that the problems comes from the fact that I load a heavy file, since I can access the django admin on the deployed version..

I'm not really knowledgeable in gunicorn/nginx (the first time I deploy an app). I'll be very thankful if you have some ideas after so much time spent on this!

The log file doesn't show any error:

```
2021-10-30 14:38:46 default[20211030t141946]  [2021-10-30 14:38:46 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
2021-10-30 14:38:46 default[20211030t141946]  [2021-10-30 14:38:46 +0000] [1] [DEBUG] Arbiter booted
2021-10-30 14:38:46 default[20211030t141946]  [2021-10-30 14:38:46 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8080 (1)
2021-10-30 14:38:46 default[20211030t141946]  [2021-10-30 14:38:46 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2021-10-30 14:38:46 default[20211030t141946]  [2021-10-30 14:38:46 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2021-10-30 14:38:46 default[20211030t141946]  [2021-10-30 14:38:46 +0000] [1] [DEBUG] 1 workers
2021-10-30 14:39:04 default[20211030t133157]  "GET /nginx_metrics" 200
2021-10-30 14:39:31 default[20211030t141946]  [2021-10-30 14:39:31 +0000] [10] [DEBUG] GET /
2021-10-30 14:39:47 default[20211030t141946]  "GET /nginx_metrics" 200
2021-10-30 14:40:04 default[20211030t141946]  [2021-10-30 14:40:04 +0000] [10] [DEBUG] POST /
2021-10-30 14:40:04 default[20211030t141946]  POST REQUEST (I click here)
2021-10-30 14:40:20 default[20211030t133157]  [2021-10-30 14:40:20 +0000] [1] [INFO] Handling signal: term
2021-10-30 14:40:20 default[20211030t133157]  [2021-10-30 14:40:20 +0000] [14] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 14)
2021-10-30 14:40:21 default[20211030t133157]  [2021-10-30 14:40:21 +0000] [1] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2021-10-30 14:40:47 default[20211030t141946]  "GET /nginx_metrics" 200
```

My app.yaml file :

```
runtime: python
env: flex
env_variables:
  SECRET_KEY: 'DJANGO-SECRET-KEY' 
  DEBUG: 'False' 
  
  DB_HOST: '/cloudsql/django-naimai:europe-west1:naimai-sql'
  DB_PORT: '5432' # PostgreSQL port
  DB_NAME: 'postgres'
  DB_USER: 'postgres' 
  DB_PASSWORD: 'DB_PASSWORD'

entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT --log-level=debug --timeout=120 django_naimai.wsgi

manual_scaling: 
  instances: 1

beta_settings:
    cloud_sql_instances: django-naimai-west1:naimai-sql

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3

resources:
  cpu: 2
  memory_gb: 2.3
  disk_size_gb: 20
  volumes:
  - name: ramdisk1
    volume_type: tmpfs
    size_gb: 2
```

My settings.py file :

```
DEBUG = os.environ['DEBUG']
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["django-naimai.oa.r.appspot.com","127.0.0.1",]
DATABASES = {"default": {
      'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
      'HOST': os.environ['DB_HOST'],
      'PORT': os.environ['DB_PORT'],
      'NAME': os.environ['DB_NAME'],
      'USER': os.environ['DB_USER'],
      'PASSWORD': os.environ['DB_PASSWORD']
}}

if os.getenv("USE_CLOUD_SQL_AUTH_PROXY", None):
    DATABASES["default"]["HOST"] = "127.0.0.1"
    DATABASES["default"]["PORT"] = 5432

GS_BUCKET_NAME="naimai_bucket"
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = "storages.backends.gcloud.GoogleCloudStorage"
STATICFILES_STORAGE = "storages.backends.gcloud.GoogleCloudStorage"
GS_DEFAULT_ACL = "publicRead"
```

Comment: Your problem appears to be crashing based upon **Handling signal: term**. You mention loading a 40 MB file. Review the code that loads the file, add exception handling and debug. If possible, debug this problem locally and then deploy it to App Engine.

Comment: You are likely running out of memory.  Try maxing out memory.

Comment: @JohnHanley I'll try to upload the file using buckets instead of loading it. Maybe that could solve the problem. You suggest to debug it : any idea how I can debug it locally ? Because each time I modify something, I need to deploy it (& wait about 30min..) to check if it's working.. Thanks :)

Comment: App Engine has documentation on how to develop locally. However, there are many techniques to develop and debug., You can develop individual functions locally, test, and then merge into your deployed app.

Comment: Thanks @gaefan, that was the idea. I tried 10 in memory and it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

As *@gaefan* suggested, I needed to max out the memory! I tried 10 in memory_gb in the yaml file and it worked.